# how to correctly check if data exist on table when posting multiple request at a time php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to confirm if a category already exist everytime I upload an image to my server.

my code.

```
public function upload(){
$album_name = Input::get('album');
$uid  = Auth::id();
//check if name being passed does exist on the table
$get_album = \DB::table('album')->where('name',$album_name)->where('user_id',$uid)->first();
    //if has result then assign id to $album_id
    if($get_album!=null)
    {
        $album_id = $get_album->id;
    }
    //else create new row and assign saved row id to $album_id
    else{
            $id = \DB::table('album')->insertGetId(['user_id' => $uid, 'name' => $album_name]);
            $album_id = $id;


    }
}
```

I am using [FineUploader](https://fineuploader.com/) on my client side to upload batch images, but the request is sent 1 image at a time.

.. but whenever I try to upload multiple images at once, with same album name.. my code ended up creating multiple line on mysql table..

Im not really sure with the issue but I think its with the timing, like query is not done yet for the first request, but another request is already made ?

how could I maybe prevent this error?

Comment: Post you `Cms` class here. What `$album_id` used for? Could you please show the rest of your code? Probably it because you check a different table. First you check the `album` table. Second you try to insert a new record to `Cms`, which is I don't know what table it is (maybe it's not `album` table).

Comment: I have used the \DB insert method but still I get the same results.. I'll update my code.. coz cms class is too long.. also I did not made it.. :)

Comment: Do **not** use selects to prevent records with duplicate values from being inserted. This is what unique indexes are for.

Comment: did you mean 'selects' = `\DB::table('album')->where('name',$album_name)->where('user_id',$uid)->first();` this part? if so could you please enlightened me a bit with that index you referring to Sir? thanks by the way!

Comment: and yes thank you very much the link you provided as duplicate worked.. !